# ffmpeg bit depth 10 bits, file size same as 8 bits?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am working on raw camera file, in 12 bits color depth. I installed ffmpeg with all libx265 features.

I used:

-pix_fmt yuv420p10le for 10 bits

But seems -pix_fmt yuv420p (8 bits) return the same file size on targetted file than yuv420p10le (10 bits)

**It is normal that the file size is the same for 8 and 10 bits ?** when I check with media info seems 8 and 10 bits is correctly tagged.

Thanks for you help

Answer (score -1):

It may surprise you, but while a raw yuv420p10le stream will be twice as big as a raw yuv420p stream, a compressed version using x264 or x265 will not vary much in size.

Encoders are very efficient and it turns out that adding 2 bits of precision will not force the encoder to produce an output that is 25% bigger (from 8 -> 10 bits).